# Why does detective Loki visit the priest?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

In the movie [*Prisoners* (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392214/), detective Loki visits a priest while looking for potential kidnaping suspects. When Loki visits the drunk and sleeping priest he finds a mummified body in his basement.

What leads does Loki have to facilitate his visit to this priest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loki is investigating other leads, after the police chief basically tells him that Alex Jones can't be the guilty party.  One of those leads is a known pedophile priest who lives in the area, and since it was two children who were abducted, it's not a bad guess when you need to leave no stone unturned.

Comment: Right, I am wondering why this priest manages to be priest after his pedophile conviction.